# Creating a stylized html header with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fitting around with creating some stylized headers for my homepage. I fell over this type of header and I was wondering if it is possible to create something like this with css. I am using Bootstrap styles if that has some importance.

[image: Stylized Header]

It might be very faint, but the header has a striped "bar" following it filling the rest of the container. I tried looking for it, but only found headers that were centered with a line before and after the header. A header type with just two lines (one at the top of the header and one at the bottom of the header) might also do the trick for me.

The header is placed inside a .container and I want the header length to  the entire length of the .container:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3><span>Projects</span></h3>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ozxk82j1/1/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you see the Recent Projects, a link so we can see the code?

Comment: I tried to dig in the code myself, but was unable to find anything. Hence the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the HTML is invalid. `span` being `inline` elements cannot contain `h3` as they are block-level.

Other than that a pseudo-element is fine here with a repeating linear gradient:

Example using flexbox although you can position the pseudo-element absolutely, give it a very long width and apply `overflow:hidden` on the `h3` for any...erm, overflow.

```css
h3 {
  display: flex;
}
h3::after {
  content: '';
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, 
    transparent, transparent 2px, 
    lightgrey 4px, lightgrey 6px);
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum.</h3>
</div>
```

The height of the pseudo-element can be adjusted to suite (`align-items:center` will keep it vertically centered) and the opacity of the 'lines' can be adjusted by using RGBA colors.

```css
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
h3::after {
  content: '';
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, 
    transparent, transparent 2px, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 4px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1)  6px);
  
  height:.5em;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor ipsum.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to change the alpha/opacity of the whole block? And also change the height of the block?

Comment: Is there any advantage in using "em" compared to "pt"?

Comment: `pt` isn't really used in web design..it's more of a print thing. I just used `em` here so it's directly related to the font-size of the heading.

Comment: Doh. My mistake. I've was meaning "px". I see. I better get used to that then. Makes much more sense to use something that is related to the font size, as "px" is directly pixel related which isn't a good practice when working with responsive designs xD